# Refactoring d3js: multiple arcs & text blocks into tidy js functions

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I am building a simple animated nav element with use of d3 (for practice).

However my code is horribly verbose because I am creating the same arc (with a few exceptions) 3 times and hard coding each one.  As a beginner I am struggling to clean this up with javascript.  Working verbose code here: http://tributary.io/inlet/7919286

In order to do so I created JSON object to represent the characteristics unique to each arc.

```
var data = {
    "arcs": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "innerRadius": 100,
          "outerRadius": 150,
          "x": 45,
          "dy": 45,
          "text": "About"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "innerRadius": 160,
          "outerRadius": 210,
          "x": 45,
          "dy": -15,
          "text": "Github"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "innerRadius": 220,
          "outerRadius": 270,
          "x": 45,
          "dy": -75,
          "text": "Contact"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to call data with here: http://tributary.io/inlet/8408617 , but it's broken and I need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to, instead of appending elements explicitly, use the `.selectAll(...).data(...).enter().append(...)` pattern to do that. That means that you need to replace all the code where you're currently explicitly appending elements with this. For the `path`s, that would look like this:

```
canvas.selectAll("path.arc").data(data.arcs)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "arc")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "path" + (i+1); });
```

The rest is a bit tedious, but not too difficult -- simply repeat for everything else. The result is [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/8415859).

Comment: Thank you Lars for taking the time to help!  When explicitly returning a function like line 60: 

.attrTween("d", function(d, i) {
      return d3.svg.arc()
          ...
 });

Why does arc() (a d3 function, right?) need to be explicitly returned in the example? Cheers

Comment: This allows you to define the properties of the arc inside that function based on the data bound to the element. I've basically just moved the code that defined it previously there.